# Is download speed from Azure web site app throttled and if so can it be configured?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a C# application hosted on an Azure web site which lets users upload and download large files. The files are in Azure blob storage and the web app serves them in 1MB blocks using CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream.

This works well though download speed seems to max out at about 5 MB/s. I get this even when accessing the app from an Azure VM which will have a low-latency connection.

It looks like some kind of throttling is taking place, where is this and can it be configured?

Tim

Comment: What plan is the website hosted under?  Sounds like something I'd expect to see in the shared hosting plans, but not the dedicated ones.

Comment: Standard site, not shared.